# webform participants extension - maximum of 9 tickets until error

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, extension

I'm using this extension for invoicing tickets bought via a webform.
https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.webformparticipants

When buying 9 or less tickets it works as required. Once 10 or more tickets are bought and the user submits payment its takes a long to load the next page which is white.

The payment is taken via eWay and the participants are entered into Civi. No confirmation emails are sent.

Without the extension enabled the payment goes through. I would like to use the extension, otherwise only 1 ticket is included on the invoice.

CMS/modules/Civi are on the latest version. Does anyone have any advice how to fix this issue? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could raise an issue if you can identify the actual issue but we have this working on webforms with up to 30 tickets afaik

Pls dig in to your logs and see if you can find more information

Comment: Hey Pete - what does that extension do that one can’t already do with webform civicrm?

Comment: Adding code to display errors to civicrm.settings.php gave this on the white screen: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 200 seconds exceeded in /home/website/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Frame/FrameListIterator.php on line 40 -----

Enabling display_errors in php.ini gave:  Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 200 seconds exceeded in /home/website/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Css/Style.php on line 1001 ------

Doesn't seem to be anything noticeable in the Drupal logs

I'll keep searching other logs. Thanks.

Comment: Unticking: Automatically email invoice when user purchases online has fixed the issue of the white page. The same issue occurs when manually printing or emailing an invoice from the View Contribution page. Seems like an issue of dompdf with large invoices?

Comment: karin - you read the Extension readme?

Comment: Yes it says “Does better handling of multiple participants registered through webforms through one or more events. Related SE question (this one)” 